# How to have a user signed in on multiple devices in Angular using Express and oAuth2?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, oauth, jwt

I am trying to allow a user to be logged into the same username on multiple devices. On the backend we are using node/express rest api with oAuth2 JWT tokens through the oauth2orize npm package.

Currently the way our backend authentication is working is that a user logs in, is sent a JWT token and a JWT refresh token. When a user logs out the tokens are invalidated. The issue we are having is a user will login on one computer and then log into the same account on another computer. When the second login happens a new token and refresh token are given to the user. Now when the user goes back to the first computer the refresh token is invalid causing the user to sign out.

One work around is we tried to persist a sessionId in a cookie but Angular appears to return a new sessionId every request. Below is an example of the requests.

```
 -- session --
l3s-kZCEUaz8TYhElVtARIwbl6PKTm_o
{ cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Fri Aug 05 2016 00:23:44 GMT+0000 (UTC),
     originalMaxAge: 31449600000,
     httpOnly: true } }

-- session --
hN961RAc2YSlmzngr3R6zXuJnp4cFF_P
{ cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Fri Aug 05 2016 00:23:46 GMT+0000 (UTC),
     originalMaxAge: 31449600000,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

Any help on having Angular give back the correct sessionId through a cookie or any other suggestions on how to handle multiple sign ins would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the server should allow multiple tokens which are simultaneously available.

Answer (score 0):

The way you tried was close to solution. Just generate a randomString instead of getting sessionId. Then while updating token check if both tokenId & randomString is same or not. If not then add as new login otherwise update the current token. Same checking apply on the logout method also.

By applying this same user will get different token for logging in different devices and the jwt token expiration will work according to the login duration of each device.